# HOw to apply regex for converting a string to camel case and remove all special chars from the string-Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am converting a string to camel case and any special chars, (numbers are ok) should be removed.

```
var str= "NOT_AVAI";  // o/p to be"Not Avai" 
var str= "HEY0-therr";// o/p to be"Hey0 Therr"
```

I'm able to convert them into camelcase:

```
return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:(^.)|(\s+.))/g, function(match) {
                            return match.charAt(match.length-1).toUpperCase();
                        });
```

but not sure how to tweak the regex in order to remove these special chars
ideas?? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g` regex to find all characters that are not alphabet and number characters then remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const cC = str => str.replace(
  /[^a-z0-9]*([a-z0-9])([a-z0-9]*)/ig, 
  (m, u, l) => u.toUpperCase() +  l.toLowerCase() + ' '
);

console.log(cC("NOT_AVAI")); // o/p to be"Not Avai" 
console.log(cC("HEY0-therr")); // o/p to be"Hey0 Therr"
```

Answer (score 1):

As @tim-hunter says, you can make it like this:

```
var str = "NOT_AVAI-linus";

// convert everything into lowercase
var result = str.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/(^|[^a-z0-9]+?)[a-z0-9]/ig, function (match) {
        console.log(match);
        if(match.length === 1) {
            // the 1st char
            return match.toUpperCase();
        }
        // char after special char
        return ' ' + match[1].toUpperCase()
    });

console.log(result);
```